# Modifying multiple JSON array elements in SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I have a SQL Server 2017 table `Orders` which has an `OrderId` primary key and `nvarchar(max)` column `Details`. This column contains a json string which represents an array of "items". Here is a sample:

```
{ items[
{
    "id": 1,
    "isDeleted": false
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "isDeleted": false
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "isDeleted": false
},
{
    "id": 4,
    "isDeleted": false
}
] }
```

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to have a single (or few) SQL statement which will allow me to update one or more of the `isDeleted` attributes in the `Details` column of this table, given an `OrderId` for the record in the table and also a list of Ids in the `Details` column to update.

So for instance, I would like to update Ids 2 and 3 to be true in the `Details` JSON string record for a given `OrderId`. I know I can do this in a while loop and using `json_modify`, but I am wondering if there is a more elegant solution with some combination of `json_modify`, `json_query` or `openjson`.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: What is the new value for the `isDeleted` key?

Comment: I am trying to change the isDeleted value to true for certain ids.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use one of the following approaches:

- Parse the `Details` JSON for each `OrderId` uisng `OPENJSON()` and explicit schema. The result is a table with columns, defined in the `WITH` clause. Update this table and return the changed data as JSON again using `FOR JSON`.
- Parse the `Details` JSON for each `OrderId` uisng `OPENJSON()` and default schema. The result is a table with columns `key`, `value` and `type` and one row  for each item (JSON object) in the `items` JSON array. Update this table and generate the `items` JSON array with string-based approach (I don't think that `FOR JSON` can generate an array of scalar values / JSON objects). Update the JSON in the source table with `JSON_MODIFY()`.
- Generate and execute a dynamic statement using `JSON_MODIFY()`

Table with data:

```
CREATE TABLE Orders (OrderId int, Details nvarchar(max))
INSERT INTO Orders (OrderId, Details)
VALUES 
   (1, N'{"items":[{"id":1,"isDeleted":false},{"id":2,"isDeleted":false},{"id":3,"isDeleted":false},{"id":4,"isDeleted":false}]}'),
   (2, N'{"items":[{"id":11,"isDeleted":false},{"id":12,"isDeleted":false},{"id":13,"isDeleted":false}]}')
```

Table with IDs:

```
CREATE TABLE ItemIds (id int)
INSERT INTO ItemIds (id) VALUES (1), (3)
```

Statement with `OPENJSON()` and explicit schema:

```
UPDATE Orders
SET Details = (
   SELECT 
      j.id AS id, 
      CONVERT(bit, CASE WHEN i.id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE j.isDeleted END) AS isDeleted
   FROM OPENJSON(Details, '$.items') WITH (
      id int '$.id', 
      isDeleted bit '$.isDeleted'
   ) j
   LEFT OUTER JOIN ItemIds i ON j.id = i.id
   FOR JSON AUTO, ROOT('Items')
)
WHERE OrderId = 1
```

Statement with `OPENJSON()` and default schema:

```
UPDATE Orders
SET Details = JSON_MODIFY(
   Details,
   '$.items',
   JSON_QUERY((
      SELECT CONCAT(
         '[', 
         STRING_AGG(
            CASE 
               WHEN i.id IS NULL THEN j.[value] 
               ELSE JSON_MODIFY(j.[value], '$.isDeleted', CONVERT(bit, 1)) 
            END,
            ','
         ),
         ']'
      )   
      FROM OPENJSON(Details, '$.items') j
      LEFT OUTER JOIN ItemIds i ON CONVERT(int, JSON_VALUE(j.[value], '$.id')) = i.id
   ))
)
WHERE OrderId = 1
```

Dynamic statement:

```
DECLARE @stm nvarchar(max) 
SELECT @stm = STRING_AGG(
    CONCAT(
      'UPDATE Orders ',
      'SET Details = JSON_MODIFY(Details, ''$.items[', a.[key], '].isDeleted'', CONVERT(bit, 1)) ',
      'WHERE OrderId = ', o.OrderId, ';'
   ),
   ' '
)   
FROM Orders o
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT o.OrderId, j1.[key]
   FROM OPENJSON(o.Details, '$.items') j1
   CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.[value]) WITH (id int '$.id') j2
   WHERE j2.id IN (SELECT id FROM ItemIds)
) a   
WHERE o.OrderId = 1

PRINT @stm 
EXEC sp_executesql @stm
```

Result:

```
OrderId Details
1   {"items":[{"id":1,"isDeleted":true},{"id":2,"isDeleted":false},{"id":3,"isDeleted":true},{"id":4,"isDeleted":false}]}
2   {"items":[{"id":11,"isDeleted":false},{"id":12,"isDeleted":false},{"id":13,"isDeleted":false}]}
```

Comment: The Dynamic statement method worked like a charm. I feel kinda silly not thinking of dynamic sql as a possible solution. I had some issues with the other method you presented. One piece of info I didn't present in my question (I apologize for the ommission) is that the json schema for the Details field is more complex than just "id" and "isDeleted". I left out other elements for brevity. It looks like your first suggestion would basically remove all other elements in the json. Is there a way to modify your first suggestion to just update the isDeleted element without touching the others?

Comment: @shenk You need to include all the keys from the `Details` JSON in the schema definition (the `WITH` clause) and in the `SELECT ... FOR JSON` statement.

Comment: That's sort of what i figured. I don't have full control over that schema, so I will go with the dynamic sql approach. Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: @shenk The answer is updated with an additional approach.

Comment: Wow, even better. Very slick. Thanks for your continued help on this!

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server is perfectly capable of performing such operation. It is another question if this is good design though.

---

This is just a demo and not production ready code, so there is a lot of space for improvement:

```
-- param section
DECLARE @OrderId INT = 1;

DECLARE @t TABLE(id INT, new_val NVARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO @t(id, new_val) VALUES(1, 'true'),(3, 'true');



--- single query
WITH cte AS (
 SELECT o.*, 
  s.[key], 
  JSON_VALUE(s.value, '$.id') AS id,
  JSON_VALUE(s.value, '$.isDeleted') AS isDeleted
 FROM Orders o
 CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(o.Details ,N'$.items') s
 WHERE o.OrderId = @OrderId
), cte_new AS (
SELECT DISTINCT c.OrderId, c.Details, s.Details_new
FROM cte c
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT  c2.id, isDeleted = COALESCE(t.new_val, c2.IsDeleted)
  FROM cte c2
  LEFT JOIN @t t
    ON c2.id = t.id
  WHERE c2.OrderId = c.OrderId
  FOR JSON AUTO) s(Details_new)
)
UPDATE o
SET Details = cn.Details_new
FROM Orders o
JOIN cte_new cn
  ON o.OrderId = cn.OrderId;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=062e323ddfcd655e34067f097b7f8eb0)**

How it works:

1. Parse JSON to tabular format
2. Perform data manipulation(here using @t as parameter)
3. Aggregate back to JSON
4. Perform UPDATE

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the right version of SQL Server to test out this code. But, you should be able to query and modify the data and generate a new json string.

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = '{"items" : [{"id": 1, "isDeleted": false}, {"id": 2, "isDeleted": false}, {"id": 3, "isDeleted": false}, {"id": 4, "isDeleted": false}]}'

SELECT *
  FROM OPENJSON(@json)
  WITH (id int '$.items.id', isDeleted bit '$.items.isDeleted')
```